# The telerik kendoDropDownList displays the items on a mobile like a actionsheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-dropdown

I'm trying to render a kendodropdownlist like this example: http://dojo.telerik.com/IJEGo, but it displays the items on a mobile like a actionsheet, no like a dropdownlist. (See my screen link at the end)

This is my index.html header:

> ```
> <link href="kendo/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
> <link href="kendo/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
> <link href="kendo/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
>
>
> <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
>
> <script src="cordova.js"></script>
> <script src="kendo/js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
> <script src="kendo/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
>
> <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
> <script src="scripts/Controlador.js"></script>
> <script src="scripts/Facturas.js"></script> </head>
> ```

My view:

```
<div data-role="view" data-title="home" data-layout="main" data-model="APP.models.home">
    <h1 data-bind="html: title" style="color:white;"></h1>
    </br>
    <!--   <input id="near-km2" />-->
    <select id="near-km2" class=".k-dropdown">
        <script>
            var kmData = [{
                    text: "5km",
                    value: "5"
                }, {
                    text: "10km",
                    value: "10"
                },
                {
                    text: "25km",
                    value: "25"
                },
                {
                    text: "50km",
                    value: "50"
                }];

            $("#near-km2").kendoDropDownList({
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
                dataSource: kmData,
                index: 1
            });
        </script>
</div>
```

What is wrong with my code ??

my screen: http://s28.postimg.org/m60mm7t25/Capture1.jpg

I will appreciate your help.